# Insert Auto date when record created in mysql using grails

Tags: date, grails

Actually i have manually entered records in mysql database-using grails but i want to show the date in a coloumn in same table.

Is there any solution for this 
 here is my controller class

```
class test {
    String company_name 
    String contact_person   
    Integer phone_no
    String status
    String place
    String address

    static constraints = {
        company_name(nullable:false)
        contact_person(nullable:false)
        phone_no(uinque:true,nullable:false)
        status(nullable:false)
        place(nullable:false)
        address( nullable:false )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `dateCreated` and `lastUpdated` in [autoTimestamp](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/autoTimestamp.html) property in GORM.

Answer (score 1):

Grails provides automatic timestamps via the "dateCreated" property:

> ### Automatic timestamping
>
> If you define a `dateCreated` property it will be set to the current
>   date for you when you create new instances. Likewise, if you define a
>   `lastUpdated` property it will be automatically be updated for you
>   when you change persistent instances.

(From the Grails user guide: [Events and auto timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping))